# Get records for each element in a array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb...so help me with this
Lets say have two collections users and articles
I have list of user IDs and need to retrieve 10 articles for each element in the list of userIDs

Comment: Please edit question with Sample docs & required o/p !!

Comment: It is not possible by mongodb only, to get the articles by the id arrays you need run query by $in:[user_ids,....] function on articles collection, then you should relate the result in the language you are using.

If you are using node.js you can do this by mongoose npm package

Answer (score 0):

Find doc for mongo aggregate function.

It's not very intuitive.